# Double escape not working for special character (Windows batch file)

Tags: windows, batch, rename, characters

This works in a batch file to remove a word from all file names, for example "UnwantedWord", on the line with "SET MODIFIED_FILENAME"...

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /r "%~dp0" %%A in ("*.*") do (
    SET ORIGINAL_FILENAME=%%~nxA
    echo.!ORIGINAL_FILENAME!

    SET MODIFIED_FILENAME=!ORIGINAL_FILENAME:UnwantedWord=!
    echo !MODIFIED_FILENAME!

    REN "%~dp0!ORIGINAL_FILENAME!" "!MODIFIED_FILENAME!"
)
```

I want to remove exclamation marks in file names, but since the "!" character and "^" are special characters, the exclamation mark needs to be double escaped by using "^^!" but when trying that, it doesn't work - the exclamation mark is not removed from the file names when the following is run:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /r "%~dp0" %%A in ("*.*") do (
    SET ORIGINAL_FILENAME=%%~nxA
    echo.!ORIGINAL_FILENAME!

    SET MODIFIED_FILENAME=!ORIGINAL_FILENAME:^^!=!
    echo !MODIFIED_FILENAME!

    REN "%~dp0!ORIGINAL_FILENAME!" "!MODIFIED_FILENAME!"
)
```

Is it possible to fix this?

Cheers folks.

Comment: If you look at what I wrote, it is the same peice of code except TripeHounds version doesn't deal with the case where the file hasn't changed or the case where your batch file itself matches the pattern.

Comment: Oh.. also, I don't care if you give me the answer or not, just take those pieces from mine and add them to yours.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to get this done.  I myself would ditch the delayed expansion and use the method of a batch function instead.  This will make "!" no longer special.

```
@echo off

for /r "%~dp0" %%A in ("*.*") do call :RenameTheFile "%%A"
goto :EOF

:RenameTheFile

   :: If somehow this batch file matches the pattern, skip it
    if "%~nx0"=="%~nx1" goto :EOF

    SET ORIGINAL_FILENAME=%~nx1
    SET ORIGINAL_FILEPATH=%~dp1

    SET MODIFIED_FILENAME=%ORIGINAL_FILENAME:some_word_or_chars=%

   :: If the file name wasn't modified, move onto the next
    if "%MODIFIED_FILENAME%"=="%ORIGINAL_FILENAME%" goto :EOF

    echo ORIGINAL_FILENAME=%ORIGINAL_FILENAME%
    echo MODIFIED_FILENAME=%MODIFIED_FILENAME%
    rename "%ORIGINAL_FILEPATH%\%ORIGINAL_FILENAME%" "%MODIFIED_FILENAME%"

goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks but this hasn't worked, with a normal word, or exclamation mark, or a double escaped exclamation mark. I can't have it going to the end of file because this is going to run before other commands (the exclamation mark is being removed so a program further on can cope with the file name).

Comment: What do you mean "I can't have it going to the end of file".  It looks like it.. but it isn't.  `call :function_name PARAM` is how you call a function in batch.  A function will be `:function_name`,  your passed parameters are %1, %2 etc.. and `goto :EOF` will make it return to the caller.  This is how we used to do it before delayed expansion was added and doesn't need the !syntax!.  Did you *TRY* it?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with your exact answer, changing "UnwantedWord" to "123" and trying it on a file called "12345.txt". Nothing happens to the file name. Using my first example in the original post, if I set it to remove "123", it works and I am left with "45.txt". I thought I could just put "^^!" there and it would work (as it already does for standard characters) but it doesn't, hence the question. What happens if you try your own answer, does it work?

Comment: It worked for the small thing I tested.  Now it works PERIOD.  I renamed files with your 123 pattern, I renamed files with exclamation points in them.  Yes, it works.  @It_Wasn't_Me isn't wrong.  Powershell is a much better tool but also.. sometimes batch is so much easier if the job is simple.